# switching an image widget in timeline

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, delay

I want to create an android widget with switching image with time delay. I have no idea about how to do this. Should I create Thread in methood onUpdate?
this example of my layout.xml file:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageViewWGT"
        android:background="@drawable/dog" />
```

and this is what I want to known how to do correct:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private int counter = 0;
    private ImageView wgt_img;
    wgt_img = wgt_img.findViewById(R.id.imageViewWGT);

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (counter%2 == 0){
                                wgt_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
                            }else
                                wgt_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);

                        }
                    });
                    counter++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);     // sleep 1 sec
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `postDelayed` method of `Handler` class like

```
// Initialisation
Handler handler = new Handler();
int counter = 0;
long switchDelay = 1000L;

// Function for switch images
public void switchImage(){
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             if (counter%2 == 0){
                 wgt_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog);
             }else {
                 wgt_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat);
             }
             counter++;
             // Recall method
             switchImage();
         }
     }, 1000);
 }
```

Comment: should I use function ```switchImage()``` in method ```onUpdate``` ?

Comment: @allobzor yes you do

Answer (score 0):

when you need to run a block of code in schedule at time you can use Timer.
look at this sample code :

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //you'r code        
        }
    } , DELAY , PERIOD);
```

add you'r code in run method and replace your delay and period of execute time instead of DELAY and PERIOD . 
DELAY and PERIOD are millisecond

also if you want run your block code one time with delay you can use Handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //you'r code
        }
    } , DEALY_MILLIS);
```

Answer (score 0):

The android has a default methood to update widget in timeline

```
<appwidget-provider
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000000">
</appwidget-provider>
```

But it works if you update the widget at least 30 minutes